# How to import multiple functions from PIL in python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I am new to image editing in python , still trying to figure out things about PIL.

I am trying to create my own filter on a image using PIL in python, but python doesn't allow me to import multiple functions.

```
from PIL import Image,Imagecolor,Imagefilter...
```

I want to use a image in computer just get familiar with using modules in Python.

when I tried using one function it says unidentified for others..like.. if I only import ImageFilter

```
import ImageFilter

img = Image.open('imagespuppy.jpg') 
out = img.filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)

img.show()
```

it shows an error saying undefined 'Image'

Need help!

Comment: In your `from PIL` statement you did not capitalize the imports correctly. `Imagecolor` has to be `ImageColor`, `ImageFilter` has to be `ImageFilter`. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: If you want to use Image class, you should import it along with ImageFilter and anything else from the library you might use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python `import` and `from` are used to include other module. suppose I have a module `math` and it has several functions

1. sqrt (square root)
2. mod (modulus)

If I want to include math module in another file of mine and use them without  their module name (`math`) I would have to do

```
from math import sqrt, mod
sqrt(25)
```

now If I have to access function with their module name

```
import math
math.sqrt(25)
```

Coming to user case Image and ImageFilter are part of PIL module. Below is how you import it

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

img = Image.open('imagespuppy.jpg') 
out = img.filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)

img.show()
```

Comment: it worked!! and also I have another doubt I have seen a few examples where the statements are typed on terminal but not any text editor. How does that work.

it says this works on a interactive shell, what does that mean

Comment: why not start with python first and then you can switch to new modules. You seem to be asking basic questions.